# Rotating points on a plane

Tags: list-manipulation, rotation

If we have a pair of coordinates $(x,y)$, let's say

```
pt = {1,2}
```

then we can easily rotate the coordinates, by an angle $\theta$, by using the rotation matrix

```
R = {{Cos[\[Theta]], -Sin[\[Theta]]}, {Sin[\[Theta]], Cos[\[Theta]]}};
```

as

```
pt2 = pt.R;
```

Now let's assume that we have a collection of points in the form

```
data = {{1}, {-0.3, 1}, {2, -0.2}, {2}, {-2, 1}, {4,-2}, {3}, {1, 1}, {-0.2, -0.3}}
```

where the integers 1, 2 and 3 count the subsets of the list `data`.

My question: how can we rotate the $(x,y)$ coordinates of the list `data` by and angle, let's say $2\pi/3$ and create a new list, `data2` of the form

```
data2 = {{1}, {rotated x, rotated y}, {rotated x, rotated y}, {2}, {rotated x, rotated y}, {roatetd x, rotated y}, ...}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Only a suggestion. The result of [`RotationTransform[θ]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RotationTransform.html) is Listable.

Comment: Any reason you have `data` formatted like this? Seems to me like the first step should be to find a better way to represent your data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should give what you want:

```
data2=data/.{x_?NumericQ,y_?NumericQ}:>RotationMatrix[\[Theta]].{x,y}
```

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this way?

```
data = {{1}, {-0.3, 1}, {2, -0.2}, {2}, {-2, 1}, {4, -2}, {3}, {1, 1}, {-0.2, -0.3}};
R = {{Cos[\[Theta]], -Sin[\[Theta]]}, {Sin[\[Theta]], Cos[\[Theta]]}};
data2 = data;
data2[[2 ;; ;; 3]] = data[[2 ;; ;; 3]].Transpose[R];
data2[[3 ;; ;; 3]] = data[[3 ;; ;; 3]].Transpose[R];
```

However, I advice not to store your data this way because, as a ragged list, it cannot be [packed](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3496).

Answer (score 1):

**Using `MapAt`:**

```
MapAt[
 RotationTransform[2π/3][#] &
 , data
 , Position[data, {_, _}]
 ]
```

$$\left\{\{1\},\{-0.716025,-0.759808\},\{-0.826795,1.83205\},\{2\},\left\{1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2},-\sqrt{3}-\frac{1}{2}\right\},\left\{\sqrt{3}-2,2 \sqrt{3}+1\right\},\{3\},\left\{-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{1}{2},\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\right\},\{0.359808,-0.0232051\}\right\}$$